# 2D int array shuffle

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, shuffle

im new to this but im tring to do a hotel reservation program.

So i have a 2D int array with ALL rooms, when i start the program i want them to be randomly shuffle in to an array called RoomNotInUse or RoomInUse (so evertime i start the program the rooms are randomly generated.

Would be awesome if anyone know a way around this :)

```
// ARRAYS
protected static int[][] rooms = {
{1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {1,5}, 
{2,1}, {2,2}, {2,3}, {2,4}, {2,5}, 
{3,1}, {3,2}, {3,3}, {3,4}, {3,5}, 
{4,1}, {4,2}, {4,3}, {4,4}, {4,5}, 
{5,1}, {5,2}, {5,3}, {5,4}, {5,5} 

};
//Declare all hotel rooms 5x5, the first number is the floor and the sec is the room
private char[][] ROIU = {

};
//Rooms not in use
private char[][] RIU = {

};
//Rooms in use


public class roomShuffle {

}
//Shuffle all rooms in 2 diffrent arrays, ROIN and RIU

public class RoomNotInUse {

}
//Displayes all the rooms thats not in use  

public class RoomInUse {

}
//Displayes all rooms in use
```

}

Answer (score 13):

You can use Fisher–Yates algorithm modified for two-dimensional arrays:

```
void shuffle(int[][] a) {
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = a[i].length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
            int m = random.nextInt(i + 1);
            int n = random.nextInt(j + 1);

            int temp = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[m][n];
            a[m][n] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign all array into list. Than use `Collections.shuffle()`.

```
    List<int[]> pair=new ArrayList<int[]>();
    pair.addAll(Arrays.asList(rooms));

    Collections.shuffle(pair);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)-

```
Collections.shuffle()
```

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsShuffle/article.html) that describes with or without Collections.

Comment: I tried this but cant get it to work with a 2d. But when i read aoubt shuffle, it says nothig about what kind of list is has to be.

Comment: @Erazx Please see the tutorial link I provided in my answer. It is very simple. ArrayList, LinkedList..they all implement list. So choose what you prefer. In the tutorial there's also array shuffle. Use that instead if you want.

Answer (score 0):

A generic shuffle method in Java should me similar to this

The important thing is that you have to swap an item with a random element that comes after in the collection ;)

```
public void shuffle(Comparable [] a){
    for(int i=0;i,a.length;i++)
         swap(a,i,getRandom(i,a.length-1);
}

private int getRandom(int min, int max){
     Random rnd = new Random();
     return min + rnd.nextInt(max-min+1);
}

 private void swap(Comparable [] a, int i, int j){
      Comparable temp = a[i];
      a[i]=a[j];
      a[j]=temp;
 }
```

Otherwise you can use the Collection.shuffle method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        int m;
        int selection;
        System.out.println("Enter number of team");
        n = scanner.nextInt();

        m = (int) Math.sqrt(n);

        int[][] matrix = new int[m][m];
        List<Integer> listMatrix = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = i * m + j + 1;
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m * m; i++) {
            listMatrix.add(i + 1);
        }
        System.out.println();

        do {
            System.out.println("what line is the card?");
            selection = scanner.nextInt();
        } while (!(selection >= 1 && selection <= m));

        selection -= 1;

        int[] values = new int[m];

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            values[i] = matrix[selection][i];
            // System.out.print(values[i] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();

        Collections.shuffle(listMatrix);

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = listMatrix.get(j + i * m);
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        scanner.close();
```